# Mysql auto-increment partially by today's date only - is this possible?

Tags: mysql

I have a requirement to auto increment an integer which I need "for the day". This is used for box numbers for orders being sent out in a day through our client's e-commerce website.

For example, the first order today would contain the box number 01. The second order would contain 02. This would be incremented specifically by a trigger or some kind of automatic function, depending on the date.

What I have described is not my exact/full requirement but I would like to know how I can code the above in particular? So if we imagine a table like this:

```
myboxnumbers (boxid [auto increment], yyyymmdd-date, boxno)
```

I would like a function in Mysql (stored procedure) to 'give me the next increment of the box number for today').

E.g.

```
function generateBoxNoForToday() {
  //1. Get today's date
  //2. Check the latest boxno in the above table for today
  //3. If no boxno yet for today, set $new-boxno = 1
  //4. If there is a boxno, my new $new-boxno = boxno + 1
  //5. INSERT INTO myboxnumbers (yyyymmdd-date, boxno) VALUES (today(), $new-boxno)
}
```

Please guide on how could I actually "do" this in Mysql? I suppose I'm too used to PHP so it's tempting to do it there :) but it makes sense that this is purely a database function and so I would like to do how to do this and the easiest route to take for such a function?

Many thanks!

Comment: With [MyISAM and BDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) storage engines - you can use multiple-columns auto-increment indexes. With other engines you'll have to maintain that manually

Comment: Ah, that's useful to know! I use Innodb however. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

It's not hard to put this into your insert statement for this table. As @AlmaDo pointed out, you need to lock the table and avoid the `COUNT(*)` operator, however.

Issue these three sql statements one after the other. Don't do anything else until you've issued all three, or your system may fail to scale up when you need it to.

```
LOCK TABLES myboxnumbers WRITE;
INSERT INTO myboxnumbers
       (yymmdd_date, boxno)
 VALUES
       (TODAY(), 
        SELECT 1 + IFNULL(MAX(boxno),0) 
          FROM boxnumbers
         WHERE yymmdd_date = TODAY()
       );
 UNLOCK TABLES;
```

To make this efficient, you need an index on `(yymmdd_date,boxno)`.

To retrieve the just-inserted `boxno` value, you can do this *immediately* after your `UNLOCK TABLES` statement.

```
 SELECT boxno FROM myboxnumbers WHERE boxid = LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Comment: Well that will fail in terms of concurrent transactions

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Ollie, looks good. Why would it fail Alma?  Can you explain?

Comment: @AlmaDo, in InnoDB? Really?

Comment: @OllieJones yes. Without proper transaction bounds your `COUNT(*)` will fail (classic case - there are two concurring rows to insert). Even worse - good chances are - this value will be cached (that's about why `COUNT` isn't "precise count" for InnoDB in common case)

Comment: Aha, OK.  I'll fix up the answer.

Comment: `LOCK TABLES`? Why in the Earth you're then using transactional storage-engine?